# Magento 1.9 Catalog Price Rule on Super product attributes configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

I currently have a product with Super product attributes configuration associated on it... I am trying to set up a catalog price rule to reduce one of the configurations price by 50%

Any help would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it by SKU on whichever simple product you want

Comment: I have tried doing this and it's still not applying to it?

Comment: I have set it to SKU  is one of , then in the actions apply 50 , on by "percentage of the original price"

Comment: did you apply the rule afterwards? Catalog rules need to be applied before they take effect

Comment: Yes I used save and apply and then re indexed my data

Comment: do you have any other rules in place that may be taking priority?